# MocMVC giving HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I'm still learning my way around testing and I'm trying to get a MockMvc test to work for me. It's a simple REST controller that at this point is only doing some authentication using information from json in the post. I've actually implemented the code, so I know it's working because I get back both the correct response with the correct input and the error messages I've put together, both in a json format. My problem is that the test keeps failing with a HttpMessageNotReadableException, even though the actual code works, so I'm assuming I don't have my test set up right. Any help you guys can give would be great.

Here's my controller

```
@Controller
public class RequestPaymentController {
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
private PaymentService paymentService;
private LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
public void setPaymentService(PaymentService paymentService){
    this.paymentService =  paymentService;
}
@Autowired
public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService){
    this.loginService =  loginService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/requestpayment", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<PaymentResult> handleRequestPayment(@RequestBody PaymentRequest paymentRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) throws Exception{
    ResponseEntity<PaymentResult> responseEntity = null;
    new LoginValidator().validate(paymentRequest, result);
    boolean valid = loginService.isLoginValid(paymentRequest, result);
    if (valid){
      responseEntity = setValidResponse(paymentRequest);
    }else {
        throw new TumsException("exception message");

    }
    return responseEntity;
}


private ResponseEntity<PaymentResult> setValidResponse(PaymentRequest paymentRequest){
    PaymentResult paymentResult = paymentService.getResults(paymentRequest);

    return new ResponseEntity<PaymentResult>(paymentResult, HttpStatus.OK);
}


}
```

And here's my test code:

```
public class RequestPaymentControllerTest {

PaymentService mockPaymentService;
RequestPaymentController requestPaymentController;
HttpServletRequest mockHttpServletRequest;
HttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse;
PaymentRequest mockPaymentRequest;
BindingResult mockBindingResult;
LoginService mockLoginService;
PaymentResult mockPaymentResult;
MockMvc mockMvc;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockPaymentService = createMock(PaymentService.class);
    mockHttpServletRequest = createMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    mockHttpServletResponse = createMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    mockPaymentRequest = createMock(PaymentRequest.class);
    requestPaymentController = new RequestPaymentController();
    mockBindingResult = createMock(BindingResult.class);
    mockLoginService = createMock(LoginService.class);
    requestPaymentController.setPaymentService(mockPaymentService);
    mockPaymentResult = createMock(PaymentResult.class);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new RequestPaymentController()).build();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mockPaymentService = null;
    mockHttpServletRequest = null;
    mockHttpServletResponse = null;
    mockPaymentRequest = null;
    requestPaymentController = null;
    mockBindingResult = null;
    mockLoginService = null;
    mockPaymentResult = null;
    mockMvc = null;
}


@Test
public void testHandleRequestPayment() throws Exception{
    initializeStateForHandleRequestPayment();
    createExpectationsForHandleRequestPayment();
    replayAndVerifyExpectationsForHandleRequestPayment();

}



private void initializeStateForHandleRequestPayment(){

}

private void createExpectationsForHandleRequestPayment(){
    mockPaymentRequest.getServiceUsername();
    expectLastCall().andReturn("testuser");
    mockPaymentRequest.getServicePassword();
    expectLastCall().andReturn("password1!");
    mockLoginService.isLoginValid(mockPaymentRequest,mockBindingResult);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(true);
    mockPaymentService.getResults(mockPaymentRequest);
    expectLastCall().andReturn(mockPaymentResult);
}

private void replayAndVerifyExpectationsForHandleRequestPayment() throws Exception{
    replay(mockPaymentService, mockBindingResult, mockHttpServletRequest, mockHttpServletResponse, mockPaymentRequest, mockLoginService);
    requestPaymentController.setLoginService(mockLoginService);
    requestPaymentController.handleRequestPayment(mockPaymentRequest, mockHttpServletRequest, mockHttpServletResponse, mockBindingResult);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/requestpayment")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    verify(mockPaymentService, mockBindingResult, mockHttpServletRequest, mockHttpServletResponse, mockPaymentRequest, mockLoginService);

}
}
```

The results of the andDo(print()) are:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = POST
     Request URI = /requestpayment
      Parameters = {}
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}

         Handler:
            Type = portal.echecks.controller.RequestPaymentController
          Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<portal.echecks.model.PaymentResult> portal.echecks.controller.RequestPaymentController.handleRequestPayment(portal.echecks.model.PaymentRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.lang.Exception

  Resolved Exception:
            Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

    ModelAndView:
       View name = null
            View = null
           Model = null

        FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 400
   Error message = null
         Headers = {}
    Content type = null
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, the test passes when I'm expecting a bad request status, but I've put in logging and I know that the ResponseBody I'm sending back has a 200 status. Like I said, this is my first time with MockMvc, so I assume I've not set something up right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An `HttpMessageNotReadableException` is

> Thrown by HttpMessageConverter implementations when the read method
>   fails.

You also get a 400 Bad Request in your response. This should all tell you that you are not sending what your server is expecting. What is your server expecting?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestpayment", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<PaymentResult> handleRequestPayment(@RequestBody PaymentRequest paymentRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) throws Exception{
```

The main thing here is the `@RequestBody` annotated parameter. So you are telling your server to try and deserialize a `PaymentRequest` instance from the body of the HTTP POST request.

So let's see the request you are making

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/requestpayment")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
```

I don't see you providing a body to the request. There should be a [`content(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#content-java.lang.String-) call somewhere in there to set the content of the POST request. This content should be a JSON serialization of a `PaymentRequest`.

Note that because you are using the `StandaloneMockMvcBuilder`, you might need to set the `HttpMessageConverter` instances yourself, ie. a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to serialize and deserialize JSON.

---

Note that the `BindingResult` parameter should come immediately after the parameter to which it's related. Like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/requestpayment", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<PaymentResult> handleRequestPayment(@Valid @RequestBody PaymentRequest paymentRequest, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
```

Don't forget the `@Valid`.

Note that this

```
requestPaymentController.setLoginService(mockLoginService);
requestPaymentController.handleRequestPayment(mockPaymentRequest, mockHttpServletRequest, mockHttpServletResponse, mockBindingResult);
```

is completely unrelated to the `MockMvc` test you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, Sotirios! This all makes sense, now I'll just play around with working it out. I appreciate such a thorough reply. I tried finding a good example of this set up, but they were all just different enough from what I'm doing to make it hard to pull it all together.

Comment: @coffeeNjava The official documentation is pretty detailed. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework).

Comment: So it is. That will be my reading for the afternoon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as sprint mvc w/ jackson (jackson-mapper-asl, v-1.9.10) deserialization requires JSON parser. And jackson requires a default constructor for http request message deserialization, if there's no default constructor, jackson will have a problem w/ reflection and throws HttpMessageNotReadableException exception.

This is to say, **all the classes/sub-classes which used as Request body, (in this case) requires a default constructor**. This costed me a few moments after I tried adding custom converter and other suggestions I got in stackoverflow in vain.

Or you can add Custom Deserializer or Mixin annotation to avoid adding default constructor hierachically everywhere. as described here: http://blogs.jbisht.com/blogs/2016/09/12/Deserialize-json-with-Java-parameterized-constructor. Check this if you're interested.

---

*Seems duplicated here > [Spring HttpMessageNotReadableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541878/spring-httpmessagenotreadableexception).*

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late to answer but just in case someone is still looking at this page.

As @Sotirios Delimanolis mentions, the problem is due to a bad request - a '*@RequestBody*' is specified in the parameter but never supplied in the request body. So, if you add that to request using '*content(someRequestString)*' as below, it should work.

```
PaymentRequest  paymentRequest  = new PaymentRequest(...);
String requestBody = new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(paymentRequest).toString();
mockMvc.perform(post("/requestpayment")
                .content(requestBody)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("SUCCESS"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.paymentAmount", is(20)));
```

*jsonPath* may be used to verify the attributes on the response. In the above example, say *PaymentResponse* has attributes *status* and *paymentAmount* in the json response. These parts can be verified easily.

You may run into errors like -

> NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/Predicate

while using jsonPath. So, make sure it is added to classpath explicitly as it is an optional dependency in *spring-test* and will not be available transitively. If using maven, do this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>      
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of the following:

- return object implements Serializable
- `@ResponseBody` annotation used on the controller method
- On your unit test

  @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {....})
  @WebMvcTest
  @AutoConfigureMockMvc